# WPF Layout/Map/Maze Generator

Tags: wpf, layout, dictionary, maze

I'm trying to give a user controls for generating a layout of boxes in WPF. I'd like to be able to add/remove rows and columns and set each box to be rotated at either 0 or 45 degrees. The result would be a sort of honeycomb of squares. I was thinking of approaching this with a ListBox and WrapPanel but after thinking about it, I think a Canvas may be better. Is there any easy methodology I could follow or will it just be trial and error with canvas positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't nearly as difficult as I thought it would be. Using a Canvas as a ListBox's ItemsPanel was relatively easy.